# React Native: How to debug exception caused by react native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

For instance, I get errors like below in Fabric. 
I can't find a clue which part of my code to fix.

How can I go about debug error like this?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to update interpolation node that has not been attached to the parent
       at com.facebook.react.animated.InterpolationAnimatedNode.update(InterpolationAnimatedNode.java:136)
       at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedNodesManager.updateNodes(NativeAnimatedNodesManager.java:524)
       at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedNodesManager.runUpdates(NativeAnimatedNodesManager.java:439)
       at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedModule$1.doFrameGuarded(NativeAnimatedModule.java:102)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.GuardedFrameCallback.doFrame(GuardedFrameCallback.java:31)
       at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher.doFrame(ReactChoreographer.java:136)
       at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ChoreographerCompat$FrameCallback$1.doFrame(ChoreographerCompat.java:107)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:909)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:655)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6940)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

- EDIT

I'm getting the error from Fabric, I can't reproduce the error on my device because I don't know where it happens for one.

Comment: You know that right? This part of code is related to animations.

Comment: Open the LogCat in Android Studio, you will see both native and React related logs.

Comment: I updated the op. I got the error message from Fabric error report. I can't reproducde it with my device. I have to get a clue where it happens from what Fabric provides.

Comment: In my experience bugsnag gives me more descriptive error logs for react native. I use fabric and bugsnag for crash logs